# How to convert a table to a vector or list in R?

Tags: r

I have a table with two columns `A`,`B` and a lot of rows. Each value like `a1` in `A` has a relation with some values like `b1`,`b2`,...,`bk` in `B`. In other words, my table is:

```
A   B
a1  b1
a1  b2
.
.
.
a1  bk
a2  b'1
a2  b'2
.
.
.
a2  b'k'
.
.
.
```

I was wondering how to convert this table to a list or vector in `R`. I converted my table to a file and used `read.table` function. Here is my code:

```
df <- read.table("MyData.csv", header = TRUE)
lapply(unique(df$A), function(x){
  paste0( x, ' = ', '(', paste( df[ df$A == x, ]$B, collapse = ","), ')' )
})
```

But the result of `lapply` has not any value.
In fact, I want to show this table for each value in `A` in this format:

```
a1 = (b1, b2, ..., bk)
a2 = (b'1,b'2, ..., b'k')
.
.
.
```

Comment: How about `lapply(split(df1$B, df1$A), toString)`

Comment: It doesn't work, first argument of split must be a vector @akrun

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It's easy, just set numerical value instead of a1,a2, b1, ... @Sotos

Comment: Sorry, No I won't. Just go over [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and post an example and also post the expected output.

Comment: I edited my post @Sotos